# Deny access to a user to see data from another users

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I am using Angular in an ASP.NET Core with ASP.NET Identity application.

I have the following controller action

```
[HttpGet("users/{userId:int:min(1)}/notes"), Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetNotesBy(userId) {

   var data = _service.getNotesBy(userId);
   return Ok(data);

} // GetNotesBy
```

I would like to restrict the access to the API so:

If a user is authenticated than it can only access its notes.
I want to prevent an authenticate user with ID=X to access the notes of a user with ID=Y. How can I block an user in this situation?

Comment: You can use `Identiy` and get the userId from `HttpContext.User` instead of sending userid in the URL

Comment: That is an idea but I want this API to be more generic so it can be used, for example, by an admin with access to all users. My idea is to check if the user has the Role admin. If yes then give access if not then check if the userId equals the Identity User Id from HttpContext.User. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does, you can use a filter or your authorization attribut to do that.

Comment: I will be using ResourceBasedAuthorization or Policy from ASP.NET Code: http://leastprivilege.com/2015/10/12/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-authorization/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what resource based authorization is aimed at.

As resource based authorization requires the actual resource it needs to happen imperatively, inside your controller.

The following is for ASP.NET Core RC1.

So, let's assume your getNotesBy returns a `Notes` class, and you have a few operations, read, write, update, delete.

First we need to define the operations. There's a suitable base class in `Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization.Infrastructure`, `OperationAuthorizationRequirement`. So we'd do something like this.

```
public static class Operations
{
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Create = 
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = "Create" };
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Read = 
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement   { Name = "Read" };
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Update = 
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = "Update" };
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Delete = 
        new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = "Delete" };
}
```

So now we have our operations, we think about how we handle authorization. You have two ways operations can succeed, if the current user owns the notes, or the current user is an admin. This equates to two handlers for a single requirement/operation.

The admin one is easy, it would look something like this;

```
public class AdminAuthorizationHander : 
    AuthorizationHandler<OperationAuthorizationRequirement, Notes>
{
    protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context, 
                                   OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement, 
                                   Document resource)
    {
        var isSuperUser = context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "Superuser" &&
                                                      c.Value == "True");
        if (isSuperUser != null)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Here we're looking for a Superuser claim with a value of True. If that's present we succeed the requirement. You can see from the method signature we're taking the OperationAuthorizationRequirement and a resource, the Notes class. This handler doesn't limit itself to a single operation, admins have rights to every operation.

Now we can write the handler which looks for the actual user.

```
public class NotesAuthorizationHandler : 
    AuthorizationHandler<OperationAuthorizationRequirement, Notes>
{
    protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context, 
                                   OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement, 
                                   Notes resource)
    {
        if (context.User.Name == resource.Owner)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }
}
```

Here we are writing something that will work for all resources, and checks an Owner property on the resource against the name of the current user.

So we have two handlers now for a single requirement, the `OperationAuthorizationRequirement`.

Now we need to register our handlers. In `startup.cs` you register handlers in DI in the `ConfigureServices()` method. After the call to `services.AddAuthorization()` you need to put your handlers into DI. You would do this like so;

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AdminAuthorizationHandler>();
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, NotesAuthorizationHandler>();
```

You can adjust the scope from `Singleton` to whatever you like if you are taking things like a `DbContext`.

Finally we're almost ready to call this, but first you need to change your controller constructor to take an instance of `IAuthorizationService`. Once you have that you can call `AuthorizeAsync()` and away you go.

```
[Authorize]
public class NotesController : Controller
{
    IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;

    public NotesController(IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
    {
        _authorizationService = authorizationService;
    }

    [HttpGet("users/{userId:int:min(1)}/notes"), Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetNotesBy(userId) 
    {
        var resource = _service.getNotesBy(userId);

        if (await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, resource, Operations.Read))
        {
            return Ok(data);
        }

        return new ChallengeResult();
    }
}
```

So what you are doing is getting your resource, and then authorizing the current user against it and the operation. When this happens all handlers which can handle that resource and operation will get called. As there are multiple handlers any one can succeed and allow access.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you handle a case where the resources is a `IEnumerable<Notes>` to only return the values the user has access for? Is that even possible with resource based approach? Let's say the user belongs to two or more groups and when getting `GetAllNotesForuser(userId)`? Just do some kind of join inside the repository to determine the users role and object he has permission too or are there any better approaches? Seems to conflict a bit with SOLID principles to do permission checks inside the repository

Comment: I'd pass the user into the repository and not care about solid 

Comment: @blowdart I think it might not be that simple. When you use DTOs what is the resource? I suppose the Entities? When you get many entities will you check authorization for all of them? I just posted a real case scenario with Resource Authorization, DTOs and Bus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622749/resource-authorization-with-dtos-and-bus-scenario.

Comment: Come rc2 you can pass ints etc rather than just objects so you can pull the resource from your repo rather than load it at the controller level which will give you more flexibility.