# Resource Authorization with DTOs and Bus scenario

Tags: asp.net-core

On an ASP.NET Core I have the following controller:

```
public class MessageApiController : Controller {

  private readonly IMediator _mediator;

  public MessageApiController(IMediator mediator) {
    _mediator = mediator;
  }

  [HttpGet("messages")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Get(MessageGetQuery query) {
    MessageGetReply reply = await _mediator.SendAsync(query);         
    return Ok(reply);
  }

  [HttpDelete("messages")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(MessageDeleteModel model) {
    MessageDeleteReply reply = await _mediator.SendAsync(model);         
    return Ok(reply);
  }

}
```

I have handlers classes with a method handle to perform this actions:

**GET** (short code for sake of simplicity)

```
public async MessageGetReply Handle(MessageGetQuery query) {

  IQueryable<Message> messages = _context.Messages.AsQueryable();

  messages = messages.Include(x => x.Author).Include(x => x.Recipients);

  // Omitted: Filter messages according to query

  List<Message> result = await messages.ToListAsync();

  // Omitted: Create MessageGetReply from result

} // Handle
```

**DELETE** (short code for sake of simplicity)

```
public async MessageDeleteReply Handle(MessageDeleteModel model) {

  Message message = await _context.Messages.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == model.Id);

  if (message != null) {
    _context.Remove(message);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  }

  // Omitted: Return reply

} // Handle
```

The authorization scenario is the following:

**GET**
1. The user must be authenticated
2. User.Id must equal Message.RecipientId;

**DELETE**
1. The user must be authenticated
2. User.Id must equal Message.AuthorId;

So I created the following resource authorization handler:

```
public class MessageAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<OperationAuthorizationRequirement, Message> {

  protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context, OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement, Message resource) {

    if (requirement == Operations.Delete) {        
      if (resource.AuthorId.ToString() == context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier))
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }

    if (requirement == Operations.Read) {
      if (resource.RecipientId.ToString() == context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)))
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }

  } // Handle

}
```

There are a few problems that arise:

1. **In GET should I pass all messages to Authorization Handler?**

   In fact the messages are filtered by MessageGetQuery.AuthorId ...
   So the authorization handler could receive MessageGetQuery.AuthorId and not a List ... 
   But feels strange since the resource is the List of Messages.
   MessageGetQuery is simply a DTO.
2. **Authorization could be coupled to DTOs (Query and Model) but does it make sense?**
   The problem arises when the DTO has less information than the Entity and I need that information to take decisions on authorization ...
3. **If using the entities as resources I loose the ability to do projection:**

   ```
   IQueryable<Message> messages = _context.Messages.AsQueryable();

   messages = messages.Include(x => x.Author).Include(x => x.Recipients);

   // Omitted: Filter messages according to query

   List<Message> result = await messages.ToListAsync();

   // CALL authorization and send the resource messages ...

   // Omitted: Create MessageGetReply from result
   ```
4. **One solution would be to have a AuthorizationHandler for Read Messages, one AuthorizationHandler for Delete message** ... The first one would take a list of messages, the second one message, ... I would however have to many classes.

Everything becomes simpler when using Entities directly in controllers and no DTOs but that, IMHO, should not be done ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RC2 we removed the object restriction in auth handlers, so you'll be able to use, for example, ints. So you could inject your repo into a handler and pull out your DTOs as you wish.

Comment: That helps. Any ETA for RC2?

Comment: None that I can share.

Comment: Please, just close the "Update sample projects" issue and release it ... :-)